Origin of the word הייבל [heibl]
During the Jewish high holidays it is a tradition for married Jewish males to don white garments and a small white hat called הייבל [heibl]. It is a somewhat larger skullcap than a kippah/yarmulke. What could be the (probably dialectal) German origins of this word? The consonants of the word doesn't seem to have any connection with the possible Hebrew triliteral roots, but the -bl diminutive suffix suggests a Germanic origin. I've tried to look it up in Yiddish and German dictionaries (Grimm usw.), but I couldn't find anything.


Most probably you couldn't find it in German dictionaries, because it is not a German word, no?

I vote to close this question, since it is off-topic here. Possible sources, according to this link: https://www.yivo.org/cimages/yivo_institute_-_yiddish_dictionaries.pdf , include: "English-Yiddish
encyclopedic dictionary" (Paul Abelson, New York, 1915) and "Groyser verterbukh fun der Yidisher shprakh" (New York, 1961)

Please [edit] your question and make clear what exactly you tried to look up in Yiddish and German dictionaries. "heibl"? Links to details and pictures of the "small white hat" ... "somewhat larger skullcap than a kippah" might also help to find out if a German word for this might be related to the hebrew word. I found a German text mentioning "Strejml" as a larger cap with fox fur, which is worn by Hasidic jews on Shabbat or marriages. https://www.gra.ch/bildung/glossar/juedische-kopfbedeckungen-inkl-kippa-und-sheitl/

@bakunin I'm interested in the German source of this word. See edit why it's reasonable to assume German origin.

I would advocate for keeping this question open. OP establishes that there is a good chance for a German origin, which makes the question on topic here.

I would reckon it originates in German Haube ("hood", "cap", "bonnet"), with possible German diminutives Häubchen, Häublein, Häubl (in the Swabian region), of which the latter would harmonize with Yiddish heibl very well. It would also fit semantically. I have no clue about the development of Yiddish language, the word just reminded me of how German Bügel is related to Yiddish bejgel (and thus English bagel). As I don't have the time right now to look for reliable sources, I just make this a comment as a hypothesis for someone else to pick up.

@JonathanHerrera I suppose that's a potential answer!

Yeah, but without deeper knowledge of the development of the Yiddish language I would consider it nothing but a somewhat plausible speculation.

Now I am starting to speculate whether the last name Hübchen is related... If anyone has Duden Lexikon der Familiennamen at hand, I would be grateful if  they could look it up for me :)

"Heibl" is also a surname which is most prevalent in Austria, (South-)Germany and Hungary. There are two theories for the meaning whereof one also refers to a diminutive of "Haube". (The other refers to „Hub(b)el“ = hill.) https://dieherkunft.com/heibl

Do you have a source for the spelling with hebrew letters? When I search in the linked Yiddish dictionary, I get "Converting הייבל to heybl" which corresponds to the German word "Hebel" = lever. Could it be that the word is הײַבל with transcription "haybl"? This gives results related to "Haube". See https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi?word=הײַבל or https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi?word=haybl or https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi?word=hayb

@bakunin - I'm not convinced that Yiddish questions are off topic here because of the similarities between Yiddish and German, at least until a Yiddish Language SE is created. On the other hand it is a different language and as a practical matter, there don't seem to be a lot of Yiddish speakers who monitor the site, and the chances that such a question would be answered in any kind of informed manner seem limited. There are less than a million native Yiddish speakers and that number is declining, so I think a more specialized forum than SE would work better for people with questions.

@RDBury: when you look up the history you'll see that the original question seemed to be about a Hebrew word, not a Yiddish one - which is why I voted to close it and commented accordingly.

@bakunin I just learned that Yiddish is written with Hebrew letters including a few special ones that don't occur in Hebrew. See https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddisch#Schrift

@Bodo Don't attribute much significance to YIVO spelling. 90% percent of Yiddish speakers don't even know that it exists. The יי can denote both [ei] and [ai], and they want to make it unambiguous. But in religious text you won't find YIVO vocalisation. A source for the spelling (third line): https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=67822&pgnum=22

The original text is translated by google as "Wenn es dämmert, erheben sie sich zum Gebet. Sie tragen einen „Kittel“ und einen „Hebel“ (eine weiße Haube)." or "When it dawns, they raise up for prayer. They wear a 'kittel' and a 'hebel' (a white bonnet)." The word "Hebel" = lever is clearly wrong, and this is probably caused by assuming the pronunciation "heibl" or "heybl" with [ei] instead of [ai]. (The word "heibl" would be pronounced with [ai] by Germans. A diphtong [ei] is rare in German.)


die Haube — lid, cap
das Häubchen, das Häublein — cute cap
's Häuble — southwestern variant of Häublein
heible — Latinized Yiddish transcription of äu in lieu of umlauts in Yiddish
heibl — loss of the end-e, very common in Yiddish


This is an ad-hoc theory, not an answer. In the east-most german dialects the diminutive doesn't get an umlaut, e.g. Burgenland (south-east Austria): "haubal". The High German word "Haube" would become more like "Haum" in dialect, because the syllable "-ben" is often shortened to "-bm" but the "b" is barely pronounced (e.g. "weben"->"we:m")

Yiddish is from the southwest though.

As has already been mentioned in the comments on the question, a reference is https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi?word=hoyb&wholeWord.

You mean the "southwest" like Poland, Ukraine, Lithuania, Hungary, etc., where Yiddish was spoken mostly in Europe? You mean that southwest?

Yiddish is a Germanic language that is based on southwestern Middle High German.

[haibl] instead of "Häubl" is delabialization or unrounding. This is also common in Bavarian dialects. Examples: Häuschen/Häuslein -> [haizl] or Leute -> [lait]
